# Double log output for standalone-ha config in jboss EAP 7

Tags: logging, log4j, wildfly, jboss-eap-7

We have recently upgraded from Jboss EAP 5.1 to Jboss EAP 7.2. 
After starting our application, we could see each actions are logged twice in the log file server.log. However the log output is normal in console output.

```
2020-05-04 04:41:57,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
2020-05-04 04:41:57,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
2020-05-04 04:41:57,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 87177ms - Started 2482 of 2655 services (425 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2020-05-04 04:41:57,181 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 87177ms - Started 2482 of 2655 services (425 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)

2020-05-04 03:51:26,345 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.servlet.dafpipeline.ProfileRequestServlet] (default task-1) [sid : LhGndXwn4RWowaUagJIhFZZ5QBLJSGPGgy6V16Pl ][pid : 53590070 ][cpoid : 610080 ]This user session is LOGGEDIN
2020-05-04 03:51:26,345 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.atg.dynamo.servlet.dafpipeline.ProfileRequestServlet] (default task-1) [sid : LhGndXwn4RWowaUagJIhFZZ5QBLJSGPGgy6V16Pl ][pid : 53590070 ][cpoid : 610080 ]This user session is LOGGEDIN
2020-05-04 03:51:26,580 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.delixl.sol.log.LogService] (default task-1) {6022}  [LhGndXwn4RWowaUagJIhFZZ5QBLJSGPGgy6V16Pl|(null)] 20200504-035126359 43.229.89.35 LhGndXwn4RWowaUagJIhFZZ5QBLJSGPGgy6V16Pl 53590070 /webshop/catalog/json/profileMarkerJson.jsp 221 200
2020-05-04 03:51:26,580 INFO  [nucleusNamespace.delixl.sol.log.LogService] (default task-1) {6022}  [LhGndXwn4RWowaUagJIhFZZ5QBLJSGPGgy6V16Pl|(null)] 20200504-035126359 43.229.89.35 LhGndXwn4RWowaUagJIhFZZ5QBLJSGPGgy6V16Pl 53590070 /webshop/catalog/json/profileMarkerJson.jsp 221 200
```

The logging configuration is default and we haven't change it. Following is the default log configuration in standalone.xml file;

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:6.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="io.undertow.request">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
```

List item

### **Update**

When I changed the log pattern to match the old Jboss, there are double logs, however, the pattern is different in one of the those double line.

Log pattern:

```
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] [%X{sid}] [pid:%X{pid}] [oid:%X{cpoid}] %m%n"/>
            </formatter>
```

Log output after changing log pattern:

```
2020-05-04 11:13:37,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] [] [pid:] [oid:] WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2020-05-04 11:13:37,931 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2020-05-04 11:13:37,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as] [] [pid:] [oid:] WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190/management
2020-05-04 11:13:37,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190/management
2020-05-04 11:13:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as] [] [pid:] [oid:] WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
2020-05-04 11:13:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10190
2020-05-04 11:13:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as] [] [pid:] [oid:] WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 116096ms - Started 2482 of 2655 services (425 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2020-05-04 11:13:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.2.0.GA (WildFly Core 6.0.11.Final-redhat-00001) started in 116096ms - Started 2482 of 2655 services (425 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

As mentioned earlier in the console (stdout) there is no duplicate but the displayed log pattern is the one which I changed.

Kindly support me out to resolve the double logging issue in server.log

Comment: How did you change the log pattern? Did you edit the XML or did you use a management interface?

Comment: I edited  the XML file.

Comment: Do you stop the server first? It's better to use the web console or CLI as the server would not need to be shutdown first.

Comment: Yes, restarted the server after changing the XML

Comment: It looks like there has been another console handler added. Just changing the pattern you list above given the config you list above should only change the output in the `server.log`.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins I noticed that the dual logs are being shown only in a clustered configuration.  I checked in other applicarion without cluster and this issue is not there.
Is there any specific logging config for standalone-ha.xml ?

Comment: Possibly. It would depend on how you have it configured really. Without seeing the full configuration it would be tough to say though.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Problem solved, I have answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a workaround for this issue, The double logging problem is probably due to the conflict between log4j in codebase and JBoss. 
 I had to Disable the following log4j configuration in Jboss to solve the double logging problem

Set export="false" in `$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/log4j/main/module.xml`

```
<module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" export="false"/>
```

Comment: Are you saying you provide log4j in your deployment? This is not the correct approach BTW. You'd want to exclude the module from your deployment, not edit it at the server level.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Thanks for pointing this out, I really couldn't figure how to disable the log4j on the codebase side, so I had to do this for a workaround.  In the codebase side I tried removing log4j jars from the lib directories and also removed entries from pom files but it didn't help. Once I find a solution I will edit the answer.

Comment: Do you have a log4j.properties or a log4j.xml configuration file in your deployment? Given your configuration examples it's very odd to me that changing log4j at all would fix this.